# $.ajax - send object for data property

Tags: javascript, jquery, asmx

I'm trying to call an asmx web service method with jQuery and pass an actual JavaScript object for the `data`, and get JSON back.  The closest I can come is this:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: JSON.stringify({ num: 12, name: "Adam" }),
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data) { alert(data.d); }
 });
```

How can I successfully make this call **without** first *stringifying* my object?

I tried this (removing the contentType)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
    type: "POST",
    data: { num: 12, name: "Adam" },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) { alert(data.d); }
});
```

But that returns the result in XML, not json.

Here's the web method:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public string HelloWorld(int num, string name) {
    return ++num + name;
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's a screenshot of the headers of the request.  Clearly content-type is set to xml for the response.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Set the ResponseFormat:
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string HelloWorld(int num, string name) {
        return ++num + name;
    }

Just a NOTE: asmx doesn't return JSON for GETs only POST</del>

---

Per Dave's Comments

> It is impossible with the ASMX and ASPX JSON endpoints. They require the application/json Content-Type and a POST request or no JSON.

Comment: That looked promising, but I'm still getting XML back.  I called that with the same setup as my second code sample - without the contentType.  Should I change anything else?

Comment: Chrome dev tools - this is what I'm seeing: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">13Adam</string>` - also, my success callback isn't firing -- at all - I should at least get an undefined alerting.

Comment: But perhaps just adding the contentType: `"application/json; charset=utf-8",` will be enough.

Comment: .net 4 - also, adding back the contentType causes the request to fail with an invalid json primitive - in other words it wants my data to be sent as a json string, instead of a javascript object, which I'd much prefer

Comment: I added that section and still nothing - it's still sending it back via xml.  I'm about to test it in FireBug, but seeing as how my success callback isn't even alerting undefined, I'm not optimistic.

Comment: Starting to think this is impossible - http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/  I'll +1 your answer and leave this open for a bit.

Comment: @AdamRackis It is impossible with the ASMX and ASPX JSON endpoints. They require the `application/json` Content-Type and a POST request or no JSON. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Dave.  I assume you'd have to use WCF to accomplish this?

Comment: @AdamRackis I'm not sure if WCF would help with that either. Using jQuery with WCF is practically identical to using it with ASMX (except of course that the server-side setup is over-complicated). If you don't mind using something on the bleeding edge, the new Web API (which you can get on CodePlex) does allow you to POST in URL encoded data and get a JSON response.

Comment: @Dave - I'm glad I'm not the only one who finds using WCF for this over-complicated.  I just *assumed* the WCF json endpoints would allow you to take in a pure object.  In any event, it's no bbi deal.  Calling JSON.stringify is not hard, especially if you have a nice utility method to do it for you .

Comment: @Joe - it occurs to me that I accepted your answer after reading Dave's comment.  Can you please update your answer stating it's impossible for the reason Dave lists, so future viewers won't be confused?